# Cuda "invalid argument" 2d array - Cellular automata

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda

I'm trying to calculate 2d cellular automata redistribution using Cuda. I'm completely new to it so I have no idea what I do wrong. I've tried many solutions that I've seen here but all give "invalid argument" when I call the kernel.

Here is a simplified version of the kernel:

```
//kernel definition
__global__ void stepCalc(float B[51][51], int L, int flag, float m, float en)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    float g=B[i][j]-0.25*(B[i+1][j]+B[i-1][j]+B[i][j+1]+B[i][j-1]);
    flag = 0;

    if (i < L-2 && j < L-2 && i>2 && j>2 && abs(g)>m)
    {
          flag = 1;
          en+=-16*g*g+8*B[i][j]*abs(g);
          B[i][j]+=-4*f*g;
          B[i+1][j]+=f*g;
          B[i-1][j]+=f*g;
          B[i][j+1]+=f*g;
          B[i][j-1]+=f*g;
    }
}
```

The main function looks like this:

```
#define L 50
float B[L+1][L+1];
//initialize B[i][j]

float g=0;
int flag = 1;
float m=0.1;
float en = 0;
while (flag==1)
{
    float (*dB)[L+1];
    int *dFlag=NULL;
    float *dEn=NULL;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dFlag,sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dEn,sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dB, ((L+1)*(L+1))*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(dB, B, sizeB, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dFlag, &flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(dEn, &en, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(16,16);
    dim3 numBlocks((L+1)/threadsPerBlock.x,(L+1)/threadsPerBlock.y);

    stepCalc<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(dB, L, dflag, m, dEn);
    GPUerrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());  //gives "invalid argument" at this line

    cudaMemcpy(B, (dB), sizeB, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&flag, dFlag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&en, dEn, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dB);
    cudaFree(dFlag);
    cudaFree(dEn);
}
```

I need to extract the new array B, the flag value and the sum 'en' over all threads. Am I even close to how a solution should look? Is it even possible? I've also tried making the host array B as float** B with no luck.

Comment: SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), for questions like these ("why isn't this code working?"), that you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It should be something that someone else can copy, paste, compile and run, without adding anything or changing anything, and see the error. Did you type this code into the browser? You are using `dflag` on your kernel parameters, but have defined `dFlag`. Why not paste in the code that you are actually using? Your method of trying to use a 2D array in the kernel will not work. You might want to search on CUDA 2D arrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code.

1. You may be overlooking the difference between passing a *value* to a kernel  and passing a *pointer*:

   ```
   __global__ void stepCalc(float B[51][51], int L, int flag, float m, float en)
                                  ^                      ^
                                  |                      |
                                a pointer              a value
   ```

   we'll come back to `B` in a moment, but for values like `flag` and `en`, passing these *by value* to a kernel has similar implications to passing by value to a C function.  It is a one-way communication path.  Since it's evident from your code that you want to use these values modified by the kernel later in host code, you will need to pass pointers, instead.  In a few cases, you have already allocated pointers for this purpose, so you have an additional type of error in that in some cases (`dFlag`) you are passing a *pointer* whereas the kernel definition expects a value.
2. Regarding `B`, passing a 2D array from host to device can be more difficult than you might initially expect, due to the *deep copy problem*.  Without covering all that ground here, search on "CUDA 2D array" in the upper right hand corner of this page, and you'll get a lot of information about it and various ways to deal with it.  Since you seem to be willing to consider an array of fixed width (known at compile-time), we can simplify the handling of a 2D array by leveraging the compiler to help us with a particular `typedef`.
3. When you're having trouble with a cuda code, it's good practice to do rigorous CUDA error checking throughout your code, not in just one place.  One reason for this is that CUDA errors incurred in a particular place will often be returned at any subsequent place in the code.  This makes it confusing if you don't check every CUDA API call, as a particular "invalid argument" error might not be due to the kernel itself, but some API call that occurred previously.
4. You typically don't want `cudaMalloc` operations in a data-processing `while` loop.  These are normally operations you do once, at the beginning of your code.  Doing the `cudaMalloc` at each iteration of the while-loop has several negative issues, one of which is that you will run out of memory (although you have `cudaFree` statements, so perhaps not), eventually, and you are effectively throwing away your data at each iteration.  Also, it will negatively impact your performance.
5. You have some of your `cudaMemcpy` transfer directions wrong, like here:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(dFlag, &flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   ```
6. Setting `flag` to zero in your kernel code will be problematic.  Warps can execute in any order, and after some warps have already set `flag` to 1 later in the kernel, other warps could begin executing and set `flag` to zero again.  This is probably not what you want.  One possible fix is to set `flag` to zero before executing the kernel (i.e. in host code, and copy it to the device).
7. Your kernel will generate out-of-bounds indexing here:

   ```
   float g=B[i][j]-0.25*(B[i+1][j]+B[i-1][j]+B[i][j+1]+B[i][j-1]);
   ```

   (just ask yourself what happens when i=0 and j=0).   The fix for this is to move this line of code inside the if-check you have for bounds checking right after it.
8. Your kernel uses a variable `f` which  is defined nowhere that I can see, for example here:

   ```
     B[i+1][j]+=f*g;
   ```

The following code is my attempt to rework your code, create a complete example, and remove the above issues.  It doesn't do anything useful, but it compiles without errors and runs without errors for me.  I haven't provided any data, so it's just a proof-of-concept at this point. I'm sure it still contains data processing errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define my_L 50

typedef float farray[my_L+1];

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

//kernel definition
__global__ void stepCalc(farray B[], int L, int *flag, float m, float *en)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    //float g=B[i][j]-0.25*(B[i+1][j]+B[i-1][j]+B[i][j+1]+B[i][j-1]);
    // flag = 0;
    float f = 1.0f;
    if (i < L-2 && j < L-2 && i>2 && j>2){
      float g=B[i][j]-0.25*(B[i+1][j]+B[i-1][j]+B[i][j+1]+B[i][j-1]);
      if (abs(g)>m)
        {
          *flag = 1;
          *en+=-16*g*g+8*B[i][j]*abs(g);
          B[i][j]+=-4*f*g;
          B[i+1][j]+=f*g;
          B[i-1][j]+=f*g;
          B[i][j+1]+=f*g;
          B[i][j-1]+=f*g;
        }
      }
}


int main(){

  farray B[my_L+1];
//initialize B[i][j]

  farray *dB;
  int flag = 1;
  float m=0.1;
  float en = 0;
  int *dFlag=NULL;
  float *dEn=NULL;

  cudaMalloc((void **)&dFlag,sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("1");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dEn,sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("2");
  size_t sizeB = (my_L+1)*sizeof(farray);
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dB, sizeB);
  cudaCheckErrors("3");
  cudaMemcpy(dB, B, sizeB, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("4");
  cudaMemcpy(dEn, &en, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("5");

  dim3 threadsPerBlock(16,16);
  dim3 numBlocks((my_L+1)/threadsPerBlock.x,(my_L+1)/threadsPerBlock.y);
  while (flag==1)
  {
    flag = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(dFlag, &flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("6");
    stepCalc<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(dB, my_L, dFlag, m, dEn);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("7");
    cudaMemcpy(&flag, dFlag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("8");
  }
  cudaMemcpy(B, (dB), sizeB, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("9");
  cudaMemcpy(&en, dEn, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("10");
// process B
  cudaFree(dB);
  cudaFree(dFlag);
  cudaFree(dEn);
}
```